# fazer direcionamento com htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Tenho um projeto onde quando o usuário digita o site com www, dá erro. Verifiquei no servidor e não tem nenhum htaccess na pasta raiz. Com isso, gostaria de saber como faço para com que o usuário digitar o www.site.com.br ou http://site.com.br fosse direcionado para a pasta  site/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em virtude de não existir o arquivo, basta criar ele em sua pasta raiz!

E adicionar uns desses dos códigos, o que adequar melhor a sua situação:

*Redirecionar endereços sem www para endereços com www*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seusite.com.br
RewriteRule ^http://www.seusite.com.br%{REQUEST_URL}[L,R=301]
```

*Redirecionar URL’s com o www para um endereço sem o www*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seusite.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.seusite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.seusite.com/site [R=301,L]
```